# How to bind joda-time with jaxb

Tags: java, jaxb, jodatime

I am having a class like this

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "executionStats")
public class ScriptExecutionStatistics {

private DateTime start;
private DateTime end;

public ScriptExecutionStatistics() { }

public ScriptExecutionStatistics(DateTime start, DateTime end) {
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
}

@XmlAttribute
public DateTime getStart() {
    return start;
}

public void setStart(DateTime start) {
    this.start = start;
}

@XmlAttribute
public DateTime getEnd() {
    return end;
}

public void setEnd(DateTime end) {
    this.end = end;
}

}
```

and I would like to serialize it in xml, so it would look like this

```
<scriptExecutionStatistics start="17.08.2015 18:17:00" end="17.08.2015 18:18:00" />
```

I know that an adapter would be necessary if I want to bind joda time with jaxb, but it is confusing I am not getting it really. so I have started with

```
public class DateTimeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<ScriptExecutionStatistics, DateTime>{
private static DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

@Override
public DateTime unmarshal(ScriptExecutionStatistics vt) throws Exception {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

@Override
public ScriptExecutionStatistics marshal(DateTime bt) throws Exception {
    ScriptExecutionStatistics stats = new ScriptExecutionStatistics();

}

}
```

Could you please help me to get it done. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DateTimeAdapter` should marshal/unmarshal `DateTime` to/from `String`e.g.

```
public class DateTimeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, DateTime>{
   private static DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

   @Override
   public DateTime unmarshal(String vt) throws Exception {
       return dtf.parseDateTime(vt);
   }

   @Override
   public String marshal(DateTime bt) throws Exception {
       return dtf.print(bt);

   }
}
```

Also you should annotate appropriate fields/getters in `ScriptExecutionStatistics` with `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateTimeAdapter.class)
@XmlAttribute
public DateTime getStart() {
    return start;
}
```